# How is possible that non independent events have the same probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-numbers

There's a question in the book "An Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and Its Applications" that I can't understand:

---

An urn contains $r$ red balls and w white balls. A sample of $n$ balls is drawn in order and without replacement. Let $X_{i}$ be $1$ if the ith draw is red and $0$ otherwise,
$i = 1, 2,..., n$.

**Show that $E(X_{i}) = E(X_{1}),i = 2, 3,..., n$.**

---

How is that possible. At the 1th draw we have a probability of $\frac{r}{r+w}$ of getting a red ball. Thus $E[X_{1}]=1 \frac{r}{r+w}+0 \frac{w}{r+w}=\frac{r}{r+w}$
.

Thus for the 2th draw we have two possible cases:

1. 1th draw we get a red ball with probability $\frac{r}{r+w}$.
2. 1th draw we get a white ball with probability $\frac{w}{r+w}$.

Thus,

$$E[X_{2}]=\frac{r}{r+w}E[X_{2}|X_{1}=1]+\frac{w}{r+w}E[X_{2}|X_{1}=0]$$

$$=\frac{r}{r+w}[1\frac{r-1}{(r-1)+w}+0\frac{w}{(r-1)+w}]+\frac{w}{r+w}[1\frac{r}{(r-1)+w}+0\frac{w-1}{(r-1)+w}]$$

$$=\frac{r(r-1)}{(r+w)(r+w-1)}+\frac{wr}{(r+w)(r+w-1)}$$

$$=\frac{wr^{2}(r-1)}{(r+w)(r+w-1)}$$

Obviously $E[X_{1}] \not = E[X_{2}]$.

Comment: The expected value of $X_2$ is not the same as the expected value of $X_2$ given $X_1=1$.

Comment: For your newest edit, your last step is wrong: $$r(r-1)+wr\neq r(r-1)\times wr$$

Answer (score 1):

No, you have calculated the *conditional* probability for getting a red ball on draw 2 *given that* a red ball was obtained on draw 1.

$$\mathsf P(R_2\mid R_1)=\dfrac{r-1}{(r-1)+w}$$

While correctly evaluated that is not actually what you want.  Rather you seek the marginal probability for the event.

The probability for getting a red ball on draw 2 is $r/(r+w)$.
By the Law of Total Probability: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(R_2)&=\mathsf P(R_2\mid R_1)\mathsf P(R_1)+\mathsf P(R_2\mid W_1)\mathsf P(W_1)\\&=\dfrac{r-1}{(r-1)+w}\cdot\dfrac{r}{r+w}+\dfrac{r}{r+(w-1)}\cdot\dfrac{w}{r+w}\\&=\dfrac{r}{r+w}\end{align}$$

And so on.

---

Per *your edit*, you should have the same result

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X_2)&=\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1=1)~\mathsf P(X_1=1)+\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1=0)~\mathsf P(X_1=0)\\&=\mathsf P(X_2=1\mid X_1=1)~\mathsf P(X_1=1)+\mathsf P(X_2=1\mid X_1=0)~\mathsf P(X_1=0) \\&=\dfrac{r-1}{(r-1)+w}\cdot\dfrac{r}{r+w}+\dfrac{r}{r+(w-1)}\cdot\dfrac{w}{r+w}\\&=\dfrac{r}{r+w}\cdot\dfrac{r+w-1}{r+w-1}\end{align}$$

---

In short, every ball has an equal chance of being in place $i$ in the draw, and $r$ of the $r+w$ are red.$$\mathsf P(R_i)=\dfrac{r}{r+w}$$

and $\mathsf E(X_i)=\mathsf P(R_i)$ ...

Comment: Nice! how can I think on this recursively process intuitively?

Comment: "Each one of the $r+w$ balls has an equal chance of being in place $i$ in the draw, and $r$ of them are red, so the probability that that ball is red is $r/(r+w)$."  The reason for calculating this probability does not change whether it is the first, last, or somewhere in between.